# Custom Delete Button in UITableViewRow not Working for iOS11

Tags: uitableview, swift4, ios11, xcode9, uicontextualaction

For iOS11 am not able to use custom delete button in table row by using `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` delegate method.
i think am missing something but what it is i don't know.Following method was not called on swipe of row.Any help would be appreciated.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: UIContextualAction.Style.destructive, title: nil, handler: { (action, view, completion) in
        //TODO: Delete
        completion(true)
    })
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .blue//UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 56/255, blue: 88/255, alpha: 1.0)
    deleteAction.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:CGSize(width:30,height:30)).image { _ in
        UIImage(named: "Icon-Trash")!.draw(in : CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:30,height:30))
    }
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
}
```

Anyone can post working code for iOS11 because i already tried from my end.

Comment: did you set the tableView's delegate?

Comment: yes i already set delegate ,other delegate methods are calling successfully .

Comment: Swipe gesture of tableView's parent view maybe avoiding it. Happens when 2 gestures clashes in a view.

Comment: @byJeevan Swipe is also working,am able to see default delete button in row but for custom button my ios11 specific method is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by setting datasource and delegate of tableview by code instead of storyboard.Also i update all of the delegate method in swift4.